# Uncaught IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. You used an empty string

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Stripe was working fine with my Laravel application, and suddenly it started giving me this error in the console: Uncaught IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. You used an empty string.

View

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('head-scripts')
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Subscribe</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <select name="plan" class="form-control" id="subscription-plan">
                        @foreach($plans as $key=>$plan)
                            <option value="{{$key}}">{{$plan}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                    <input id="card-holder-name" type="text">

                    <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
                    <div id="card-element"></div>

                    <button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
                        Pay
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create('card');
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
        const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
        const plan = document.getElementById('subscription-plan').value;

        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
                clientSecret, cardElement, {
                    payment_method_data: {
                        billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                    }
                }
            );
            if (error) {
                // Display "error.message" to the user...
            } else {
                // The card has been verified successfully...
                console.log('handling success', setupIntent.payment_method);

                axios.post('/subscribe',{
                    payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
                    plan : plan
                }).then((data)=>{
                    location.replace(data.data.success_url)
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

The .env file has the correct keys. Someone please help me figure this out, it was working perfectly fine until now. I ran the following commands along with restarting the server multiple times:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Show us your Stripe configuration, the error tells you clearly you have an empty string, we need for information.

Comment: I added the blade file. Let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: Can you log `const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');` and tell me if there is actually a proper result, your actual key (don't post your key here...)?

Comment: I looked in the console and it shows this: const stripe = Stripe(''); It is not fetching data from env. file. However, it was before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since this line:

```
const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
```

is not getting the Stripe key from `.env`. You need to clear your cache.

Run following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

If that does not work I would try to create a hidden input with your key inside:

```
<input type="hidden" id="stripe_key" value="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY) }}"/>
```

And access the value like this:

```
const stripeKey = document.getElementById('stripe_key').value;
```

There is also a way to require a .dotenv extension in your webpack mix file.

With that you can directly access the key using javascript.

Comment: As you posted this answer, I also figured it out. I ran php artisan config:clear and it worked. For some reason, I was running php artisan config:clear, and THEN php artisan config:cache. Possibly because I was running php artisan config:cache after was causing the error?? Thank you so much for helping me, I was super upset because I just got this working and then it suddenly stopped working and I had no idea what I did wrong

Comment: @JakeScervino glad to here I had a similiar mistake a couple weeks ago, now I know that one really has to clear the .env file since it always caches the key in it.

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb:

> Never ever use env directly in the code

So instead of `env(SOME_VAR)` it should always be `config('some_var')` otherwise when you run `php artisan config:cache` on production it will never be read.

Answer (score 0):

the error is occured from javascript code :

```
 const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
```

STRIPE_KEY is found empty ''

Comment: Yes, but it is not empty. The correct API keys are in my .env file. I ran config:clear and restarted server multiple times. It was working perfectly fine and now its not fetching the data from my .env.

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for you help as well.